# Spring Batch Job Listeners Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement where I read data from database in chunks and write it into the files and upload the files to the target folder. I now have a requirement to capture the count of rows written into the files and time taken to complete the whole job. I am trying to use jobexecutionlistener to capture the job status but please advise how can i capture rows return in respective chunks so that i will add this information into the final job status information?

Comment: Spring Batch already logs all of that for you why would you need a listener for that. It is all in the database tables of Spring Batch.

Comment: What  if I have to capture additional information or application field values?

Comment: That isn't what your question is about if you have a different question then ask that question. Or describe your exact use case instead.

Comment: Based on the question, `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` and `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` would have all the relevant data you've mentioned (read counts, write counts, start/end times, etc.).

Comment: StepExecutionListener has all the read count and write count, skip count etc methods. maybe that's what you want.